# For which (constant) values $p$ and $q$, all the solutions of equation: $x''+px'+qx=0$ go to $0$ at $t \to +\infty$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives

For which (constant) values $p$ and $q$, all the solutions of equation: $x''+px'+qx=0$ go to $0$ at $t \to +\infty$ ?

So I've found the solution of our 2nd order differential equation which is

$x(t) = 
C_1 e^{-\frac{1}{2} t \left(\sqrt{p^2 - 4 q} + p\right)} + 
C_2 e^{\frac12 t \left(\sqrt{p^2 - 4 q} - p\right)}
$ .

Now I don't really know what to do with it. Do I have to calculate limits from $x(t)$ or something like that?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

P.S. Sorry for the title, I'm not sure how should I formulate it.

Comment: Yes, discussing the limit in terms of $p,q, C_1$ and $C_2$ is an option, though a bit tedious. The other one is knowing already what those limits are in the case $C_1=0\land C_2=1$ and in the case $C_1=1\land C_2=0$. However, the scientific content is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The corresponding characteristic equation is
$$ r^2+pr+q=0. \tag{1}$$
Let roots of (1) be $r_{1,2}$.

Case 1: $p^2-4q>0$. Then $r_1,r_2$ are negative if $p>0, q>0$.

Case 2: $p^2-4q<0$. Then $r_1,r_2$ are complex and have negative real parts if $p>0$.

Case 3: $p^2-4q=0$ Then $r_1=r_2=-\frac{p}{2}<0$ if $p>0$. In this case, $q>0$ .
Thus if $p>0, q>0$, (1) has roots with negative real part and hence
$$ \lim_{t\to\infty}x(t)=0. $$

Answer (score 1):

It asks for all solutions (which includes all possible $C_1$ and $C_2$ values, as these characterize the solutions) having $\lim_{t\to\infty} x(t) = 0$, so you choose those $p$ and $q$ which guarantee this.

E.g. what is needed to make the solution $C_1 = 1, C_2 = 0$ to behave this way?
And what for the solution $C_1 = 0, C_2 = 1$?

For $\Delta = p^2 - 4 q \ge 0$ we have no imaginary components in the exponents and need
$$
-\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{p^2 - 4 q} + p\right) < 0 \quad \wedge \quad
 \frac{1}{2}  \left(\sqrt{p^2 - 4 q} - p\right) < 0  \iff \\
\sqrt{p^2 - 4 q} + p > 0 \quad \wedge \quad
\sqrt{p^2 - 4 q} - p < 0 
$$
Now
$$
\sqrt{p^2-4q} - p < 0 \iff
\sqrt{p^2-4q} < p \iff
q > 0 \wedge p > 0
$$
For $\Delta < 0$ we need $p>0$.

Comment: For $C_1=1, C_2=0$: we know that $ \lim_{t \to \infty} x(t) = + \infty$ so I guess I would take $q>0$ so the limit will be equal to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint/Sketch:**
I will assume that $p,q \in \mathbb{R}$.
So based on your work, the general solution (almost every time) is
$$x(t) = C_1 e^{\frac{-1}{2} t (\sqrt{p^2 - 4 q} + p)} + C_2 e^{\frac12 t (\sqrt{p^2 - 4 q} - p)}$$
1. If $p^2-4q>0$, then everything is real. So we need both $e^{\text{something}}$ to go to $0$. That means we need the something to be negative. So we want: $\sqrt{p^2 - 4 q} + p>0$ and $\sqrt{p^2 - 4 q} - p<0$ at the same time (because $t$ is positive).

2.If $p^2-4q<0$, then we are caring about the real part of the something only because the imaginary part will mean oscillation only (As [user539887](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/539887/user539887) pointed it out in the comments). In that case, the $\sqrt{p^2-4q}$ is pure imaginary, and the $p$ is real. so we need the $\frac{-tp}{2}$ to be negative, so $p>0$.

3.If $p^2 - 4 q=0$, the general solution is different:
$$x(t)=C_1e^{-\frac{tp}{2}}+C_2te^{-\frac{tp}{2}}$$
In this case, you will need the something to be negative, so $p>0$.

Comment: What about $x''+2x'+2x=0$? Then $p^2-4q<0$, and the general solution is $e^{-t}(C_1 \cos{t}+C_2\sin{t})$, which, beyond any doubt, goes to zero as $t\to\infty$, whatever $C_1$ and $C_2$ are.

Comment: @user539887 You are totally right!

Comment: @user539887 I think I fixed it now.

Comment: In your case 1., I think that it is enough to assume $-p+\sqrt{p^2-4q}<0$ (because then the second root of the characteristic equation, that is, $-p-\sqrt{p^2-4q}$ will be negative, too).

Comment: @user539887 Well, yes. But it was just meant to be a sketch, not a complete solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I kinda understand it how to find p and q.
I have also another exercise, it's really similar, but the equation is: $x''+qx=0$, the characteristic equation is $r^2+q=0$, hence $x(t) = c_2 sin(\sqrt{q} t) + c_1 cos(\sqrt{q} t) $

Comment: @MacAbra And you also want it to go to $0$ as $t \to +\infty$?

Comment: @Botond indeed.

Comment: @user539887 Yes, The limit is $0$ which only need the real part of the roots less than $0$.

Comment: @MacAbra If $q$ is real, then I'd look for the solution in the form of $x(t)=A\sin(Bt+C)$, just for simplicity (or for the same, with $\cos$). You can get that $x(t)=A\sin(C+\sqrt{q}t)$. We know that $C+\sqrt{q}t \to \infty$ as $t \to \infty$, so it will oscillate almost every time. So you need $\sqrt{q}$ to be $0$. But then, $x(t)=A\sin(C)$, so you need $\sin(C)=0$ or $A=0$, so it might go to $0$. But in the $q=0$ case, the complete solution is $x(t)=C_1t+C_2$, which will converge to $0$ if and only if $C_1=C_2=0$. So it CAN converge if and only if $q=0$, but the convergence is not guaranteed

Comment: @MacAbra But you can reach the same result with your solution as well: For $\sqrt{q} \neq 0$ both of the $\sin$ and $\cos$ are divergent, so the only possibility is $q=0$. But then, $x(t)=c_2 \sin(0)+c_1 \cos(0)=c_1$...

Answer (score 1):

The general solution of the homogeneous equation have form $x(t) = c_1e^{r_1t} + c_2e^{r_2t}$ with roots of its characteristic $r_1$ and $r_2$. The limit $$\lim_{t\to \infty} x(t) = c_1\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{r_1t} + c_2\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{r_2t}$$ is $0$, if the limt of terms $e^{r_1t}$ and $e^{r_2t}$ are $0$. Therefore the roots $r_1$ and $r_2$ are negaitive real number that it is $$r = \frac{-p\pm\sqrt{p^2-4q}}{2} < 0.$$ It is two inequalities $$p > \sqrt{p^2 - 4q}\quad \mathrm{and}\quad p^2 - 4q \geq 0$$ that they become $$q > 0\quad \mathrm{and}\quad p^2 \geq 4q.$$
Therefore, if two inequalities $q > 0$ and $p^2 \geq 4q$ are hold, then the general solution of the homogeneous equation $\ddot{x} + p\dot{x} + qx = 0$ have limit $$\lim_{t\to \infty} x(t) = 0.$$
If $D = p^2 - 4q < 0$, what will happen ? The roots have form $r_1 = \alpha + i\beta$ and $r_2 = \alpha - i\beta$ with $$\alpha = -\frac{p}{2}\quad \mathrm{and}\quad \beta = \frac{\sqrt{p^2 - 4q}}{2}.$$ And the solution become $$\begin{aligned}x(t) &= e^{\alpha t}(c_1e^{i\beta t} + c_2e^{-i\beta t}) \\ &= e^{\alpha t}[(c_1+c_2)\cos (\beta t)+ i(c_1-c_2)\sin (\beta t)] \\
 &= ae^{\alpha t}(e^{i(\beta t - \gamma)})  \\
&= ae^{\alpha t+ i(\beta t - \gamma)}\end{aligned}$$ with $$a = \sqrt{(c_1+c_2)^2 + (c_1-c_2)^2}\quad\mathrm{and}\quad e^{i\gamma} = \frac{c_1+c_2}{a}+ i\frac{c_1-c_2}{a}.$$
Therefore if $\alpha < 0$ and $\beta < 0$ which is $$p > 0\quad \mathrm{and}\quad p^2 < 4q,$$ the general solution of the homogeneous equation have also limit $$\lim_{t\to \infty} x(t) = 0.$$
Therefore if the coefficient $p > 0$ in the homogeneous, its general solution have the limit $0$.

Comment: See my comment below Botond's answer.